# Sidecar redis instance in k8s job

Tags: kubernetes, sidecar

My use case:

1. Running a bunch of my own processing in a kubernetes `Job`
2. Want to associate a short-lived `redis` cache for the lifetime of the `Job` processing
3. The `Job` should complete when my processing finishes, and `redis` should go away

I can't figure out how to accomplish this, though I feel like I can't be the first one to need this.

If I add `redis` as a second container to the job's `spec`, then my processing completes but `redis` keeps on going, and the `Job` never completes.

I could try and add `redis` to the container with my processing, running it first as a daemon and then running my own code, but this feels wrong to me.

I've read about sidecar patterns and some other people looking for what I need, but I didn't see any clear solution. I saw what look to me like hacks with shared volumes and livenessProbes.

How is this best accomplished?

Comment: Redis's data structures are fairly primitive; if the cache doesn't need to be persisted or shared between processes, can you just keep it in-process (using language-native hash tables or priority queues, for example) rather than using Redis?

Comment: @DavidMaze - while it doesn't answer my question, it's a good point - food for thought.  I'll think about it while I search for other solutions.  The best I've come up with so far is to call the redis `SHUTDOWN` command from my code when it's done. Seems fragile but will work, I guess

Comment: Running Redis SHUTDOWN command in PreStop hook of main container against the Redis sidecar container sharing the same Pod IP address, is a good approach in my opinion as well.